# cannot resolve "occupation" given input column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

All,

I'm getting an error while running a GroupBy in Pyspark even though occupation column exists. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
grajee

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your column names have leading whitespaces. If so, then you can use this before grouping

```
from functools import reduce

oldCols = df.columns
newCols = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]

df = reduce(lambda data, idx: data.withColumnRenamed(oldCols[idx], newCols[idx]), range(len(oldCols)), df)
```